# How to apply Top Navigation in results.aspx in SP 2013's Search Center site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, search-center

I am trying to find out how to apply top navigation for the Enterprise Search Center's Results.aspx file.

Currently we have not set the top navigation on this page. But customer found this as an issue in our DMS portal which is built on SP 2013.

Any ideas how to apply the top navigation on this system page? I am able to see `results.aspx` is  residing in `15/templates/layouts folder`.

Is it possible to modify/manipulate this page?

Answer (score 1):

*results.aspx is residing in 15/templates/layouts folder.*

It appears as if `results.aspx` is an application page, and therefore contents of this page can't be updated without having to perform deployment. [However you can always change master page of an application page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx)

P.S. I recommend you start using out of the box search results content page (based on search page layout) which gives you a lot of flexibility and consistent design together aligned with site master page. Once you created the page, it can be updated in search center too.